# Can't decode UTF8 for turkish letters

Tags: c#, encoding

I am trying to fetch rows from a SQL-Table with the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.
I tried generating a conversion with [this tool](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator), but it didn't really help.

In the table the cell contains:

```
Hocam ” You can go out ” ne demek ?
+ Dışarı çıkabilirsin.
- Teşekkürler
```

and decoded using the tool (with encoding code windows-1254/iso 88599) it's:

```
Hocam ” You can go out ” ne demek ?
+ D??ar? ç?kabilirsin.
- Te?ekkürler
```

I am setting the encoding like this

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
//wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
wc.Encoding = new CustomEncoding();
```

Comment: `I am trying to fetch rows from a SQL-Table` and you use WebClient. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Where does CustomEncoding code from, is it an SQL table or a WebService and, most important, what exactly is coming in when you look at it as `byte[]` ?

Comment: @L.B, I am requesting an XML via GET over HTTP with the WebClient

Answer (score 2):

```
  Dışarı çıkabilirsin
```

The letter ı is Unicode codepoint U+0305.  The next letter, ş, is U+0351.  You can find a code chart for ISO-8859-1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout).  And note that neither of these codepoints appear on that chart.

So what you know for a fact is that 8859-1 cannot possibly encode those characters, getting a `?` is therefore entirely expected.

There are other code pages that *do* have these characters, designed to handle Turkish.  Like ISO-8859-3, ISO-8859-9 and Windows-1254.  And of course UTF-8, it can reproduce any codepoint in Unicode, unlike these other 8-bit encodings.  But that's not it, you'd see "DÄ±ÅarÄ± Ã§Ä±kabilirsin" instead.

Which one you should try next is impossible to guess from the question.  You've got 3 good candidates, give them a shot.  Talk to the server owner next, it may well be his problem with him using the wrong code page to encode the dbase data.  Only he can fix that.

Comment: I am the owner of the DB. How else whould I encode the table?

Comment: You are using WebClient.  What does it connect to?  That one.

Comment: It connects to a .php and the XML its generating starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.Encoding = utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'Silverlight Tex Encoding Class Generator' it will fix